# Calendar needs cannot be meet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, scheduling

My needs are reasonably simple but I cannot seem to find a working solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. I don't want to start implementing something from scratch if I can use a open source solution that is well stablished and I can eventually contribute in some way.

**My Requirements**

1- I need to have all events stored in the database so I can fetch them (and their content) with a background process for manipulation. I will process all events once/twice a day for any given day. Processing mainly consists of sending out reminders etc.

2- I need to allow recurring events.

3- I need custom forms and application specific custom fields for all events.(this seemed to leave google calendar out)

4- UI needs to display events depending on user logged in.

5-  all day events not required

**What I have looked at so far:**

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/): Seems the most plausible although I haven't yet figured out how to accomplish #3 above.

[event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar): I have no idea how to implement recurring events efficiently using this solution. It seems like I would have to implement it from scratch using iCal's standards etc. Does not sound like fun. Any suggestions here?

[Ice_Cube](http://seejohncode.com/ice_cube/): This would potentially help with the event_calendar recurring event implementation.

I have not worked with calendars before so I might be missing something really simple. Please let me know your thoughts.

Env: Rails 3.1, looking for gem/plugin/JQuery solution. If not found will try to implement from scratch. =) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Check [dhtmlxScheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml), it solves all above requirements.

Also, there is a [ROR integration sample](http://support.dhtmlx.com/x-files/samples/ruby_scheduler.zip)

Comment: Since I posted this question, I started rolling my own solution from event_calendar mentioned above. I will definitively take a look at this though for future reference. Thanks for mentioning.